# Bash IP IF THEN ELSE Statement

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, grep

I need to run one script from several machines but each machine requires unique commands to be executed.

I thought that a bash script would be able to do this but I'm not too savvy in this department.

The code I require would look similar to the below code (or would it). I know that it's far from perfect or functional but it's really there just to help to express what I am looking for.

Could somebody please help me with this script?

```
#/bin/bash
IP= ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -c 7-17 

If [$IP -eq 192.168.32.1]
then mkdir IPFolder-1
more code...
else
if [$IP -eq 192.168.32.2]
then mkdir IPFolder-2
more code...
else
if [$IP -eq 192.168.32.5]
then mkdir IPFolder-5
more code...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are the execution steps completely different from box to box? Are they same commands with different paths,names, etc? Are you running into some specific problem with the script you've started writing?

Comment: "Help" how? What do you want us to do? What is your question? And how are we supposed to deduce your intentions from a script that, by your own admission, doesn't represent them accurately?

Comment: This might be a simpler way to grab the IP: `ifconfig eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet addr:)[0-9.]+'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use double brackets, spaces are important:

```
IP=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -c 21-34)
if [[ $IP = 192.168.32.1 ]]; then
  mkdir IPFolder-1
elif [[ $IP = 192.168.32.2 ]]; then
  mkdir IPFolder-2
fi
```

Note: on Ubuntu 11.10, I had to use cut -c 21-34, adapt as necessary.

Comment: An easier (more reliable) way to get the address would be to install `ifdata` and use `ifdata -pa eth0`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, ifconfig is localized, maybe it's why Sam has to cut 21-34 instead of 7-17.

Use `LANG= ifconfig` to have it in english everywhere.

It seems that [ifconfig have other quirks](http://jengelh.medozas.de/2008/0219-ifconfig-sucks.php) to know.

(It should be more a comment than an answer, but i can't comment yet.)