# Bash shell 'if' statement comparing outputs from different commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, grep

Using an adapted [example given to me by Sam Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809689/bash-ip-if-then-else-statement/7809853#7809853)  which I have tweaked so I can show what I'm trying to achieve.

```
app1=$(someapp -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 5-10)
if [$app1 = (someapptwo -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 20-25)]; then
mkdir IPFolder-1
elif ...blah blah
fi
```

Can I use grep as show above or am I barking up the wrong tree? or should it look a little some thing like this:

```
app1=$(someapp -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 5-10)
app2=$(someapptwo -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 20-25)
if [$app1 = $app2]; then
mkdir IPFolder-1
elif ...blah blah
fi
```

Comment: Did you notice Sam Ruby said "spaces are important"?

Answer (score 7):

At least in other shells, you need to be a lot more careful with spaces; the square bracket is a command name and needs to be separated from previous and following words.  You also need (again in classic shells for certain) to embed the variables in double quotes:

```
app1=$(someapp -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 5-10)
if [ "$app1" = "$(someapptwo -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 20-25)" ]
then mkdir IPFolder-1
elif ...blah blah
then : do this instead...
fi
```

You could do it all in one line (well, two because I avoid the horizontal scrollbar whenever possible):

```
if [ "$(someapp    -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c  5-10)" = \
     "$(someapptwo -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 20-25)" ]
then mkdir IPFolder-1
elif ...blah blah
then : do this instead...
fi
```

Or you could do it with two separate command captures:

```
app1=$(someapp    -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c  5-10)
app2=$(someapptwo -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 20-25)
if [ "$app1" = "$app2" ]
then mkdir IPFolder-1
elif ...blah blah
then : do this instead...
fi
```

*Update:*
Some extra quotes added.  It would be possible to quote the assignments too:

```
app1="$(someapp -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c  5-10)"
```

No harm would be done; it isn't strictly necessary with `bash` (but it may well have been necessary with archaic Bourne shell).

Comment: You should also put double-quotes around the `$(somecommand)` bits, at least in the `if` statements (it's not necessary when assigning them to a variable, but I tend to do it anyway for consistency).

Comment: I tend to quote them; I got castigated because it isn't always necessary, and I'm trying to lighten up.  Maybe I shouldn't bother.  I'd love to have access to a real Bourne shell to test more of what is the new bash behaviour vs what is legacy behaviour.  I'll add the double quotes - thanks.

Comment: Classic shells would include System V Bourne shell (and System III or 7th Edition versions), for example, and possibly the Korn shell too.  Bash would be a modern shell.

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer to the value of your expression by prepending a $:

```
...
if [ "$app1" = "$(someapptwo -flag | grep usefulstuff | cut -c 20-25)" ]; then
...
```